# Visual Studio Windows Phone 8 Tutorials

Tags: windows-phone-8

Where can i find some nice tutorials on developing apps that target windows phone apps specifically?

I want to take advantage of direct x.

Is Developing Windows phone apps remotely the same as developing a windows application?

Ima newb but i just read an entire c++ book.

I am currently in Asia, And can not google at the moment :D

Comment: Well done on reading the book! Try http://www.bing.com - this is Asia friendly :)

Comment: I forgot to thank you, :) Bing works!

Answer (score 2):

You could find great tutorials at http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/

and developing apps for widows phone is quiet the same but you've gotta learn a few new class since WP and windows don't fully share the WinRT Core. You can develop apps using C++ but i would recommend to go for C# because it is far flexible that C++ and getting help is easy...